# can sitemesh3 be used by spring boot 3.x?

Tags: spring-boot, sitemesh

spring boot 3.x must be to use java 17
In java 17, almost javax is replace by jakarta
like
javax.servlet.Filter is replace to javax.servlet.Filter

when I extend ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter to setting decorator

```
public class WebSiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter{

     @Override
        protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
            builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/views/decorator.jsp");
     }
}
```

and implements WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class WebSiteMeshConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    
   @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean siteMeshFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        WebSiteMeshFilter siteMeshFilter = new WebSiteMeshFilter();
        filter.setFilter(siteMeshFilter);
        return filter;
    }

}
```

it show me error `The method setFilter(Filter) in the type FilterRegistrationBean is not applicable for the arguments (WebSiteMeshFilter)`

that is because setFilter is use jakarta.servlet.Filter
but ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter is implements Filter (javax.servlet.Filter)

I try use cast to let `javax.servlet.Filter` to be `jakarta.servlet.Filter`
but when run this project, it show me `ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter`

how can I do to fix this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Sitemesh 3.2.0. This version is compatible with spring boot 3.x. You can additionally check out the documentation: https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh3?tab=readme-ov-file This version uses Jakarta packages instead of javax